# Split a String till a word in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have to split a string till a word in JavaScript.

```
var urlCurrent = "www.example.com/web/americas/home";
var siteNames = ["americas","international","europe","asia-pacific","africa-middle-east","russia","india"];
var siteNamesJoin = siteNames.join('|');
var siteUrlCurrent = urlCurrent.split(siteNamesJoin);
```

Here, I have to split the `urlCurrent` string using the words in the array. so that at the end I have to get `www.example.com/web/americas`. I am not getting the regex for that.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377). Is the URL always going to be in this format? Because you might not need `siteNames`. You could get the substring upto the last `/`. What if the domain name has `india` in it?

Comment: If you literally split `urlCurrent` at the string `americas` for example, you'd get `["www.example.com/web/", "/home"]`. But this is obviously not what you want to achieve. Do you rather want to get everything before and including the siteNames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using regex & match

```
var urlCurrent = "www.example.com/web/americas/home";
var siteNames = ["americas","international","europe","asia-pacific","africa-middle-east","russia","india"];
var regex = new RegExp(siteNames.join('|'));
var match = urlCurrent.match(regex);
if(match) {
  var url = urlCurrent.substr(0, match[0].length + match.index)
console.log(url);
} else {
//invalid url 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
new RegExp("^.*?(?:" + siteNamesJoin + "|$)")
```

The pattern will look like

```
^.*?(?:americas|international|europe|asia-pacific|africa-middle-east|russia|india|$)
```

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E.*%3F(%3F%3Aamericas%7Cinternational%7Ceurope%7Casia-pacific%7Cafrica-middle-east%7Crussia%7Cindia%7C%24)):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?:americas|international|europe|asia-pacific|africa-middle-east|russia|india|$)` - any of the values in between pipes or end of string.

See JS demo:

```js
var urlCurrent = "www.example.com/web/americas/home";
var siteNames = ["americas","international","europe","asia-pacific","africa-middle-east","russia","india"];
var siteNamesJoin = siteNames.join('|');
var match = urlCurrent.match(new RegExp("^.*?(?:" + siteNamesJoin + "|$)"));
var siteUrlCurrent = match ? match[0] : "";
console.log(siteUrlCurrent);
```

NOTE: if the `siteNames` "words" may contains special regex metacharacters, you will need to escape the `siteNames` items:

```
var siteNamesJoin = siteNames.map(function (x) { return x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') }).join('|');
```

Also, if those words must match in between `/` or end of string, you may adjust the pattern:

```
var match = urlCurrent.match(new RegExp("^(.*?)/(?:(?:" + siteNamesJoin + ")(?![^/])|$)"));
```

See another demo.

```js
var urlCurrent = "www.example.com/web/americas/home";
var siteNames = ["americas","international","europe","asia-pacific","africa-middle-east","russia","india"];
var siteNamesJoin = siteNames.map(function (x) { return x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') }).join('|');
var match = urlCurrent.match(new RegExp("^.*?/(?:(?:" + siteNamesJoin + ")(?![^/])|$)"));
var siteUrlCurrent = match ? match[0] : "";
console.log(siteUrlCurrent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you, i guess you don´t need a regex:

```
var urlCurrent = "www.example.com/web/americas/home";
var siteNames = ["americas","international","europe","asia-pacific","africa-middle-east","russia","india"];
var siteNamesJoin = siteNames.join('|');
var siteUrlCurrent = urlCurrent.split(siteNamesJoin);

const pos = urlCurrent.split("/")[2];
let url;

for(const index in siteNames) {
  if(pos === siteNames[index]) {
     url = urlCurrent.substring(0,urlCurrent.lastIndexOf("/"));
  }
}

console.log(url);
```